# PHP cURL Sending File error type is missing, type does not have a valid value, file is missing

Tags: php, file, curl, post

I am trying to upload a file in a server using PHP cURL, My code is like following

```
<?php
     if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    
        if(isset($_FILES['file']['name'])){
    
            $cfile = curl_file_create($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['file']['type'],$_FILES['file']['name']);
        
            $postRequest = array(
                'file'      => $cfile,
                'caption'   => 'My Test Caption'
            );
        }
    }
    $curl = curl_init();
    $url = 'myAPIURL';
    $token = 'mySecretToken';
    
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($postRequest),
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Authorization: Bearer '.$token,
            'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        ),
    ));
    
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
?>


<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file"> <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload file">
</form>
```

The Documentation of the API is written like this

> REQUEST BODY SCHEMA: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> file(required) :string  [File to upload]
>
> caption(string) : The caption

I am getting this error in return

`"**type is missing, type does not have a valid value, file is missing**"`

Could you guys help? Much much appreciated. Have no idea about this.

Comment: Have your done a `var_dump` of the POST/FILES arrays to determine if they contain he information you expect? Does `$cfile` get created OK? What version of PHP is it?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, var dump provide json error returned from server error : type is missing as mentioned. $cfile gets created. Php version 7. I tried providing extra postfield type : image/png , then message change to invalid type provided

Comment: Do not use `http_build_query`, pass `$postRequest` (which won't _exist_, btw., if `$_POST['submit']` and/or `$_FILES['file']['name']` are not set - so why are you proceeding with making the request in that case?) for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` directly; and remove the Content-Type header.